# drawing and JLabel on a Frame

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, jlabel

I wanted to create a caterpillar game using Java Frame. It basically has two players trying to occupy a square to increase their scores. I've been using two classes:

the caterpillar class

```
package caterpillar;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;

class Caterpillar {

    private Color color;
    private Point position;
    private char direction;
    private Queue<Point> body;
    private Queue<Character> commands;
    private int score;

    public Caterpillar (Color c, Point p){
        color = c;
        direction = 'E';
        body = new LinkedList<Point>();
        score = 0;
        commands = new LinkedList<Character>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            position= new Point(p.x + i, p.y);
            body.offer(position);
        }   
    }

    public void setDirection(char direction){
        commands.offer(new Character(direction));
    }

    public void move(CaterpillarGame game){
        if(commands.size()>0){
            Character c = (Character)commands.peek();
            commands.poll();
            direction = c.charValue();
            if(direction == 'Z') 
                return;
        }

        Point np = newPosition();
        if(game.canMove(np)){
            body.poll();
            body.offer(np);
            position = np;
        }
        score+=game.squareScore(np);    
    }

    private Point newPosition(){
        int x = position.x;
        int y = position.y;
        if(direction == 'E') 
            x++;
        else if(direction == 'W') 
            x--;
        else if(direction == 'N') 
            y--;
        else if(direction == 'S') 
            y++;
        return new Point(x, y);
    }

    public boolean inPosition(Point np){ //check if position has alredy been occupied
        Iterator <Point>it = body.iterator();
        while(it.hasNext()){
            Point location = it.next();
            if(np.equals(location)) 
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public int getScore(){
        return score;
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g){
        g.setColor(color);
        Iterator <Point>it = body.iterator();
        while(it.hasNext()){
            Point p = it.next();
            g.fillOval(5 + CaterpillarGame.SegmentSize * p.x,
                    15 + CaterpillarGame.SegmentSize * p.y,
                    CaterpillarGame.SegmentSize,
                    CaterpillarGame.SegmentSize);
        }
    }

}
```

the game class:

```
package caterpillar;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class CaterpillarGame extends Frame{

final static int BoardWidth = 60;
final static int BoardHeight = 40;
final static int SegmentSize = 10;
private Caterpillar playerOne;
private Caterpillar playerTwo;
private Point square;
private int number; //points the players will get if occupy the square
private Random generator;
private JLabel score1, score2;// scores of two players

public static void main(String[] args){
    CaterpillarGame game= new CaterpillarGame();
    game.run();
}

public CaterpillarGame(){
    setBackground(Color.GREEN);
    setVisible(true);
    setSize((BoardWidth+1)*SegmentSize, BoardHeight*SegmentSize + 30);
    addKeyListener(new KeyReader());
    playerOne = new Caterpillar(Color.blue, new Point(20, 10));
    playerTwo = new Caterpillar(Color.red, new Point(20, 30));
    addWindowListener(new CloseQuit());
    generator = new Random();
    number = 1;
    score1 = new JLabel("Player One: "+playerOne.getScore());
    score2 = new JLabel("Player Two: "+playerTwo.getScore());
    this.add(score1);
    this.add(score2);
    square = new Point(newSquare());    
}

public void run(){
    while(true){
        movePieces();
        repaint();
        try{
            Thread.sleep(100);
        }catch(Exception e){}
    }
}

public void paint(Graphics g){
    playerOne.paint(g);
    playerTwo.paint(g);
    g.setColor(Color.white);
    g.fillRect(square.x, square.y, 10,10); //line 62, exception thrown
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.drawString(Integer.toString(number), 10, 10);
}

public void movePieces(){
    playerOne.move(this);
    playerTwo.move(this);
}

public boolean canMove(Point np){
    int x = np.x;
    int y = np.y;
    if((x<=0)||(y<=0))
        return false;
    if((x>=BoardWidth)||(y>=BoardHeight))
        return false;
    if(playerOne.inPosition(np))
        return false;
    if(playerTwo.inPosition(np))
        return false;
    return true;
}

private class KeyReader extends KeyAdapter{
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
        char c = e.getKeyChar();
        switch(c){
        case 'q': playerOne.setDirection('Z'); 
                  break;
        case 'a': playerOne.setDirection('W');
                  break;
        case 'd': playerOne.setDirection('E');
                  break;
        case 'w': playerOne.setDirection('N');
                  break;
        case 's': playerOne.setDirection('S');
                  break;
        case 'p': playerTwo.setDirection('Z');
                  break;
        case 'j': playerTwo.setDirection('W');
                  break;
        case 'l': playerTwo.setDirection('E');
                  break;
        case 'i': playerTwo.setDirection('N');
                  break;
        case 'k': playerTwo.setDirection('S');
                  break;
        }
    }
}

public Point newSquare(){
    Point p = new Point(generator.nextInt(51), generator.nextInt(31));
    while(playerOne.inPosition(p)||playerTwo.inPosition(p)){
        p = new Point(generator.nextInt(51), generator.nextInt(31));
    }
    number++;
    return square = p;
}

public int squareScore(Point p){
    if(p.equals(square)){
        newSquare();
        return number;
    }
    return 0;
}

private class CloseQuit extends WindowAdapter{
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e){
        System.exit(0);
    }
}

}
```

this is what i have so far, but i got several problems when i ran the program:

1. the JLabels, square, and string didn't show up
2. it kept throwing java.lang.NullPointerException
   [image: the exception occurs at line 62]
3. how do i have the program stopped when the score of one player reaches a certain number?
4. how to check if a caterpillar touches the square?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is line 62 of CaterpillarGame.java? More importantly, you need to learn the general concepts of how to debug a NPE (NullPointerException). **You should critically read your exception's stacktrace to find the line of code at fault, the line that throws the exception, and then inspect that line carefully**, find out which variable is null, and then trace back into your code to see why. You will run into these again and again, trust me.

Comment: you have many Problems, you try to Paint graphical Components, but i cannot find any kind of SWT/SWING Containers (Frame/JFrame, ..etc). your run-methode calls the paint-methode, this needs the Parameter Graphics, and this is null, that causes nullpointerexception

Comment: You will want to read the tutorials *before* trying to create Swing GUI's.

Comment: Make sure you are calling `super.paint` first. Having said that, you should avoid overriding paint of top level containers like `Frame` and instead use `paintComponent` of components that extend from `JComponent` instead...

Comment: @ Hovercraft Full Of Eels I marked line 62 in the code

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels The OP's also overriding `paint` of `Frame`, which then calls `paint` of the `Caterpillar` class.  The OP could have called it `draw`, but the process is the same :P

Comment: Your code works for me, except, to generates a `ConcurrentModificationException` because the thread is trying to update the position of the `Caterpillar` while it's trying to `paint` it :P

Comment: You have a concurrency issue (race condition).  The frame is been made visible BEFORE you create the `square` object, meaning that the frame is been painted BEFORE `square` is initialized, and is `null` when `paint` is called

Comment: actually a big part of this program is provided by my instructor. i have no idea why he uses Frame instead of JFrame and JPanel.

Answer (score 1):

> the JLabels, square, and string didn't show up

They are, you're just screwing with the paint process so badly that you're preventing them from been painted.  Also, I "believe" that `java.awt.Frame` uses a `BorderLayout`.

This is one of the reasons we generally discourage people from overriding `paint`, it's far to easy to break the paint chain

Add a call to `super.paint` before you perform any custom painting.

```
@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);
```

I'd prefer that you used `paintComponent` from a `JComponent` based class and add that object to your frame, but you seem to have restrictions from doing so...

Also, change the layout manager to something like `FlowLayout` to get both labels on the screen.

See [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) for more details

> it kept throwing java.lang.NullPointerException

This seems to be a race condition.  Essentially, you are calling `setVisible` on the frame BEFORE you've finished initialising the requirements of the UI, which is causing `paint` to be called BEFORE the frame is fully initialized.

Call `setVisible` last.  Better yet, don't call `setVisible` from within the constructor...

> how do i have the program stopped when the score of one player reaches a certain number?

... In your "game loop" you need to be checking that state of the score and breaking out of the "game loop" when the required state is meet...

> how to check if a caterpillar touches the square?

That's a much more complicated question.  Essentially you could use the `interests` or `contains` method of a `Rectangle` (or other `Shape` object).  You know where the `Point` of the `square` and "segments" of the `Caterpillar` are.  You know the size of the `square` and the "segments".

You need to compare each of the segments to see if they intersect the are of the `square`.  Take a closer look at [`java.awt.Rectangle`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Rectangle.html) for more details